# Django : Send HTTP 200 OK response before inserting POST request data into DB

Tags: python, django, database, http, django-models

How do I write a view in Django which handles the POST request in such a way that I return HTTPresponse before saving/inserting the POST data into the DB?

Comment: The only way I could suggest is task queue to delay the insert. But it is a pain.

Comment: As Andrey mentions, the only way is to use an async queue (like Celery or Huey). Now the real question is: why do you want to do that ? Writing to the DB is usually fast enough...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Any way to profile and measure that? Django DebugToolbar?

Comment: Yes. Debug toolbar will give you that kind of info.